# How to void the particular item out of multiple items in PayPal?

Tags: paypal

I want to know how to void the particular item out of multiple items in PayPal or other transaction.

For example user have ordered the three products & made the payment,after that user called me and void the one product and do not void other two products.

But I have one transaction id for whole product, If I am going to void then whole products transaction has been voided,but it should not be like this. I want to void one product.

Answer (score 0):

You can call DoCapture and set COMPLETETYPE=Complete. This will only capture the amount you specified in the DoCapture API call and mark the authorization as completed, and thus 'void' any remaining funds you may have authorized.

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoCapture